# C++ cin freezes when entering very large strings with zero whitespace

Tags: c++, input, iostream, cin, large-data

I'm trying to input a command line argument with a huge length (roughly 1000-2000 characters) and whenever I use cin, getline, scanf, or any kind of stream reader, my execution stops. I'm using XCode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002). This is my code:

```
int main() {
   string S = "";
   cin >> S;
   cout << S;
   return 0; 
}
```

This is my input that I've been testing. I don't control the input length, I must use as is. There are zero whitespace characters:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This is where the code execution has been stopping:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__read_nocancel:
0x7fff8ff6407c <+0>:  movl   $0x200018c, %eax
0x7fff8ff64081 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x7fff8ff64084 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x7fff8ff64086 <+10>: jae    0x7fff8ff64090            ; <+20>
0x7fff8ff64088 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x7fff8ff6408b <+15>: jmp    0x7fff8ff5ebdd            ; cerror_nocancel
0x7fff8ff64090 <+20>: retq   
0x7fff8ff64091 <+21>: nop    
0x7fff8ff64092 <+22>: nop    
0x7fff8ff64093 <+23>: nop
```

EDIT:
I've been fiddling around and I've been able to find that the upper limit is 1024.

Comment: [Unable to Reproduce](https://ideone.com/X6LcQP)

Comment: `a command line argument` is no subject of stream I/O. You should use argc/argv of main or some operating system function returning the command line (note a command line of 1000 characters might be too huge)

Comment: That works pretty well at least for such an input of 15kb... (OSX). Or did I missed something?

Comment: @DieterLücking  On Ubuntu 15.10, there is an upper limit on how long a command line might be, but appears to be fairly large  "getconf ARG_MAX" reports 2097152. "xargs --show-limits" reports 131072 chars.

Comment: @Xirema So I guess it's a compiler issue then. That's good to know. I wonder what's up with mine? I switch to something else and get back to everyone.

Comment: I doubt this is a compiler issue. Exactly how are you trying to provide the input to your program? You mention "a command line argument", but none of `cin`, `getline`, or `scanf` read command line arguments at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce ... here is my version.

I am using the std::stringstream to simplify the filling of a ram-based-file with 26K characters.  std::stringstream is very useful for these kinds of simple tests.

```
  void t397input(std::stringstream& ss)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i<1000; ++i)
        ss << "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // 26000 chars

     std::cout << "ss.str().size(): " << ss.str().size() << std::endl;
  }

  int t397(void)
  {
     std::stringstream ss;
     t397input(ss);

     std::string S;
     ss >> S;
     std::cout << S.size() << "\n"
               << S << std::endl;
     return 0;
  }
```

At the end of the following output,
ubuntu reported the duration as .121 seconds.

---

> ./dumy397
>
> ss.str().size(): 26000
>
> 26000
>
> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
>
> ...
> pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> real   0m0.121s
>
> user   0m0.004s
>
> sys    0m0.000s